# how to select multiple columns from a table based on different where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, aggregate-functions

I want to combine these 4 queries into one query:

```
select SUM(AMOUNT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
from PAYMENT;
```

```
select SUM(AMOUNT) as NOT_SETTLED_AMOUNT
from PAYMENT
where STATE = 0;
```

```
select SUM(AMOUNT) as SETTLED_AMOUNT
from PAYMENT
where STATE = 1;
```

```
SELECT CREATION_DATE
        FROM PAYMENT
        WHERE PAYMENT_ID = (SELECT max(PAYMENT_ID) from PAYMENT)) as LATEST_PAYMENT_DATE;
```

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INQUIRY
```

Comment: Please update your question (using editable text) to show sample data and the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform all 4 computations in a single table-scan, using conditional aggregation. As for the creation date of the latest payment id, we can use [Oracle's `keep` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html):

```
select
    sum(amount) as total_amount,
    sum(case when state = 0 then amount else 0 end) as not_settled_amount,
    sum(case when state = 1 then amount else 0 end) as settled_amount,
    max(creation_date) keep(dense_rank last order by payment_id) as latest_payment_date
from payment
```

Note that this is more efficient than other approaches that use subqueries and/or union.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `UNION` them.

Add another column which says what's what.

As all UNIONed queries have to have the same number of columns and same **datatypes**, and as the last query returns `date` value (while all the rest returns numbers), *convert* them all to strings with `to_char`:

```
SELECT 'total amount' what, TO_CHAR (SUM (amount)) AS amount FROM payment
UNION ALL
SELECT 'not settled amount', TO_CHAR (SUM (amount))
  FROM payment
 WHERE state = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'settled amount', TO_CHAR (SUM (amount))
  FROM payment
 WHERE state = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'creation date', TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  FROM payment
 WHERE payment_id = (SELECT MAX (payment_id) FROM payment)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'max ID', TO_CHAR (MAX (id)) FROM inquiry
```

Answer (score 0):

For first 3 best for you would be ROLLUP and CASE:

```
SELECT
    CASE state 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'NOT_SETTLED_AMOUNT'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'SETTLED_AMOUNT'
        ELSE 'TOTAL_AMOUNT'
    END
    , SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM 
    PAYMENT
GROUP BY ROLLUP (state);
```

For creation date just use UNION ALL like: Littlefoot says

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals in your SUM.

```
WITH totals AS
(
    SELECT
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 0 THEN AMOUNT END) AS NOT_SETTLED_AMOUNT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS SETTLED_AMOUNT,
        MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
    FROM PAYMENT
)
SELECT 
    t.TOTAL_AMOUNT,
    t.NOT_SETTLED_AMOUNT,
    t.SETTLED_AMOUNT,
    p.CREATION_DATE AS LATEST_PAYMENT_DATE 
FROM totals t LEFT OUTER JOIN PAYMENT p ON t.MAX_ID = p.ID;
```

If you're okay with getting the max CREATION_DATE as the last payment date rather than by looking at the CREATION_DATE of the last ID then the query gets more simple:

```
SELECT
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 0 THEN AMOUNT END) AS NOT_SETTLED_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS SETTLED_AMOUNT,
    MAX(CREATION_DATE) AS LATEST_PAYMENT_DATE
FROM PAYMENT;
```